# Powershell error + Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter"

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell module which writes logs when powershell script executes

PowerShell Module: module.psm1

```
function Write-Log
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [alias("LogText")]
        [string]$Text,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)]
        [alias("TextType")]
        [string]$Type,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
        [alias("LogFile")]
        [string]$File
    )
    begin{
        $stamp = (get-date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        $output = ""
    }
    process{

        switch ($Type)
        {
           'info' {
                $output = "$stamp <span style='color;#23a1cc'><strong>INFO`t: </strong></span> $Text<br>"
                break
            }
            'warning' {
                $output = "$stamp <span style='color;#f5a900'><strong>WARNING`t: </strong></span> $Text<br>"
                break
            }
            'error' {
                $output = "$stamp <span style='color;#cf000f'><strong>ERROR`t: </strong></span> $Text<br>"
                break
            }
            'success' {
                $output = "$stamp <span style='color;#009944'><strong>SUCCESS`t: </strong></span> $Text<br>"
                break
            }
            'header' {
                $output = "<H3 style='color;#009944'>$Text</H3><br>"
                break
            }
            default {
                $output = "$stamp <span style='color;#23a1cc'><strong>INFO`t: </strong></span> $Text<br>"
                break
            }
        }

        $output | Out-File -FilePath $File -Append
        Write-Host "$Type : $Text"
    }
    end{
        $stamp = ""
        $output = ""
    }
}
```

I import this module in my powershell script  script.ps1

when I call

```
Write-Log -Text "Successfully Imported Module" -Type 'info' -File 'C:\Temp\log.html'
```

I get Error

```
Write-Log : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Type'. Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter".
```

I am new to powershell and using switch for the first time... Not sure whats happening and bit confused as I find articles saying switch only accepts Boolean ? now sure how that works out in my scenario.. ANy suggestion would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Code copy-pasted "as is" works for me. Try to `Import-Module` with parameter -force, otherwise you may load old code.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks.. -Force patched things up.. working as expected